# How should I mount a hanging closet panel with no wall for its hang rail?

Tags: mounting, studs, closet

I am planning to install a new closet system in my second bedroom using one of those "hanging closet" kits - the kind where you secure a cleat to a wall that side panels hang off of.

The shape of the closet makes using the hang rail a little difficult though. Specifically, the closet houses my water heater in a little nook on the left side of the closet. The layout looks like this:

[image: closet layout]

The plan is to have 3 separate sections, where the left section covers the water heater. It would look like

[image: closet design]

with a layout like this:

[image: closet sections layout]

Because there's no wall behind where the single hang bar will be, my plan is to just fasten its left panel directly into studs behind the leftmost wall. Its right panel (which doubles as the middle section's left panel) would be sitting directly over the corner where the two walls meet.

My questions are

1. Will my plan of fastening the left section's panel directly to studs in the wall provide sufficient support to the closet, or is this a bad idea?
2. This might be a very stupid question, but I know corners where drywall meet typically have the metal corner guard to protect the edge. Is it okay to drive a fastener for the hang rail through this metal guard?

Comment: You want to make sure of easy access to the water heater.  Studs are the prefer mounting spots.  Metal drywall corners are used on outside corners, not often on inside corners.

Comment: Yes, the hang bar and shelf will be above the top of the water heater. The right panel of the left section will be hanging directly on top of an outside corner, not an inside corner

Comment: An outside corner I might want to drill a pilot hole first, to not crack the drywall mud.  It is quite thin on corners and very easy to crack.  Screws are easier to control than nails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fastening anything to the left wall should be rock solid.  The details are important.  Look at exactly how your system fastens to the wall.  Make sure the left panel can be fastened, somehow, to studs and/or the hanging rail can be driven *through* the left panel and fastened directly to a stud.

Mounting the other end of the tall hanger to the corner of the wall should be ok if it's not *right on the edge*.   The metal corner bead is protecting the two sheets of drywall that meet at the corner.  If you are too close to the corner, your screws will go through the bead and into the edge of the side-wall of the nook.  You need to be far enough to the right that your mounting hardware will connect to the studs at the corner.  The bead itself is not structural.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The panel on the left wall is made of wood, so my plan was to screw through the panel into the the stud with a washer on the screw. For the right side, is there any way to ensure I'm hanging over the stud and not drywall? Is a stud finder reliable for corners like this?

Comment: A stud finder is not useful here.  There has to be a stud there.  Since you're going to be installing shelving there, there is no harm in drilling small test holes.  You can determine exactly where the stud is, and whether it is wood or metal, and use appropriate screws.  Assume there is 1/2 to 5/8 inches of drywall, and 1.5 inches (or more) of stud at the corner. Drill your first test hold 1 inch from the surface (side of the nook and you'll hopefully find solid wood.